# Why is my if statement always return true when looping through div's by classname?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm looking to loop through several Div tags with the same class name. While looping through I am checking the height of each div tag. If the height exceeds the normal 105px due to a line break, I need to add a new class to those select Divs. Using console.log I can see each Div, the index number, height, and text inside. However, when I write the If statement, it is returning true every time and for every div with that class name.

As soon as the line breaks on the "Super Long Text" the border should turn blue and only on those select Div's.

```js
$('.sub-service-title').each(function(index) {

 var subServiceHeight = $(this).css('height');
 var minHeight = 105;
 console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).text() + $(this).css('height'));

 if ($( subServiceHeight > minHeight )) {
  $(this).addClass('break');
 }

 else {
  $(this).removeClass('break');
 }

});
```

```css
.sub-service-title {
  min-height: 105px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 10px 0px;
}

.break {
border: 5px solid blue;
}

h1 {
font-size: 50px;
line-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sub-service-title"><h1>Short Text</h1></div>
<div class="sub-service-title"><h1>Super Super Super Super Super Long Text</h1></div>
<div class="sub-service-title"><h1>Short Text</h1></div>
<div class="sub-service-title"><h1>Super Super Super Super Super Long Text</h1></div>
<div class="sub-service-title"><h1>Short Text</h1></div>
```

Comment: What do you think `$(...)` _is_, or _does_? Try `$(true)` or `$(false)` in your browser's console right now, and observe the results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need `$(...)` wrapping your condition.

```
if (subServiceHeight > minHeight) {
```

`$(...)` is used in jQuery for finding elements based on a selector.

You are also using `.css('height')` which returns a string, and then comparing it to a number. Seeing as you're using jQuery you could use .height() to get the height of the element

```
var subServiceHeight = $(this).height(); // returns number
```

Comment: Removing that always sets the condition to false and never returns true.

Comment: That would mean the condition is not satisfied. You are using `.css('height')` which returns a string, and then comparing it to a number. Seeing as you're using jQuery you could use `.height()` to get the height of the element

Comment: Right on! That fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: You can mark the answer as correct so people can find it in future

Answer (score 0):

Updated code that worked perfectly.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.sub-service-title').each(function() {

  var subServiceHeight = $(this).height();
  var minHeight = 105;
  //console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).text() + $(this).height());

  if ( subServiceHeight >= minHeight ) {
   $(this).addClass('break');
  }

  else {
   $(this).removeClass('break');
  }

 });
});


$( window ).on("resize", function() {
 $('.sub-service-title').each(function() {

  var subServiceHeight = $(this).height();
  var minHeight = 105;
  //console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).text() + $(this).height());

  if ( subServiceHeight >= minHeight ) {
   $(this).addClass('break');
  }

  else {
   $(this).removeClass('break');
  }

 });
});
```

```css
.sub-service-title {
  min-height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 10px 0px;
}

.break {
border: 5px solid blue;
}

h1 {
font-size: 30px;
line-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sub-service-title"><h1>Short Text</h1></div>
<div class="sub-service-title"><h1>Super Super Super Super Super Long Text</h1></div>
<div class="sub-service-title"><h1>Short Text</h1></div>
<div class="sub-service-title"><h1>Super Super Super Super Super Long Text</h1></div>
<div class="sub-service-title"><h1>Short Text</h1></div>
```